# Put every Hash Element inside of an Array Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a Hash like this:

```
my_hash = {"a"=>{"a1"=>"b1"}, "b"=>"b", "c"=>{"c1"=>{"c2"=>"c3"}}}
```

And I want to convert *every* element inside the hash that is also a hash to be placed inside of an Array.

For example, I want the finished Hash to look like this:

```
{"a"=>[{"a1"=>"b1"}], "b"=>"b", "c"=>[{"c1"=>[{"c2"=>"c3"}]}]}
```

Here is what I've tried so far, but I need it to work recursively and I'm not quite sure how to make that work:

```
my_hash.each do |k,v|
  if v.class == Hash
    my_hash[k] = [] << v
  end
end
 => {"a"=>[{"a1"=>"b1"}], "b"=>"b", "c"=>[{"c1"=>{"c2"=>"c3"}}]}
```

Comment: @sergiotulentsev, now both answers are deleted. Both should be turned into community wiki answers.

Comment: @theTinMan: Hm, I see one still standing. No need to have them both.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Yes, the other was undeleted right after the comment-exchange.

Comment: Would it not be more convenient if all the hash values were arrays, as you could always check if `h[k].is_a? Hash`.

Comment: Why the down votes?  I clearly state my need and my attempted solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your code into a method and call it recursively.

```
my_hash = {"a"=>{"a1"=>"b1"}, "b"=>"b", "c"=>{"c1"=>{"c2"=>"c3"}}}

def process(hash)
    hash.each do |k,v|
      if v.class == Hash
        hash[k] = [] << process(v)
      end
    end
end

p process(my_hash)
#=> {"a"=>[{"a1"=>"b1"}], "b"=>"b", "c"=>[{"c1"=>[{"c2"=>"c3"}]}]}
```

Comment: Good one, Wand. You could alternatively write `hash[k] = [process(v)]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I did not mess with the original code much, its pretty much what OP had.  Feel free to update it as its community wiki

Answer (score 2):

Recurring proc is another way around:

```
h = {"a"=>{"a1"=>"b1"}, "b"=>"b", "c"=>{"c1"=>{"c2"=>"c3"}}}
h.map(&(p = proc{|k,v| {k => v.is_a?(Hash) ? [p[*v]] : v}}))
 .reduce({}, &:merge)
# => {"a"=>[{"a1"=>"b1"}], "b"=>"b", "c"=>[{"c1"=>[{"c2"=>"c3"}]}]}
```

It can be done with single reduce, but that way things get even more obfuscated.